# Delete database record using plugin from admin panel

Tags: php, database, wpdb

I have a plugin that reads data from WordPress database. I want the admin to be able to delete a record from the database using the data's ID.
how do i do this...
i have tried

```
 if ($_GET) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['in_delete'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM bookings" );

        foreach ( $result as $print ) {
            $id = $print->id;
            $del =  $wpdb->delete( 'bookings', $id );
            if ( $del ) {
                echo "<script>
                        alert('record deleted');
                      </script>";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and my button is

```
<form action="" name="operations" method="get" >
    <input type="button" name="in_delete" value="Delete" style="color:#fff; height:19px; width: 60px; font-size:10px; background-color: red;cursor: pointer;"><br>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, so your code can't work, because you use `$wpdb->delete` incorrectly.

Let's take a look at [Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#DELETE_Rows). `$wpdb->delete` takes 3 params (one is optional):

- **$table** (string) (required) Table name.
  Default: None
- **$where** (array) (required) A named array of WHERE clauses (in column -> value pairs). Multiple clauses will be joined with ANDs. Both $where columns and $where values should be 'raw'.
  Default: None
- **$where_format**(string/array) (optional) An array of formats to be mapped to each of the values in $where. If a string, that format will be used for all of the items in $where. A format is one of '%d', '%f', '%s' (integer, float, string; see below for more information). If omitted, all values in $where will be treated as strings unless otherwise specified in wpdb::$field_types.
  Default: null

And it returns:

> It returns the number of rows updated, or false on error.

### So what's wrong with your code?

```
$id = $print->id;
$del =  $wpdb->delete( 'bookings', $id );
```

You pass `$id` as second param, but it's just a number, and you should pass an array of where clauses...

### So how should it look?

```
foreach ( $result as $print ) {
    $del =  $wpdb->delete( 'bookings', array( 'id' => $print->id ) );
    if ( $del ) {
        echo "<script>
                  alert('record deleted');
              </script>";
    }
}
```